# Angular via Browserify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify

I just want to do the following using browserify:

```
var angular = require('angular');
angular.etc ...
```

The [Angular page on npmjs.org](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular) gives an alternative using [exposify](https://github.com/thlorenz/exposify), but I would like to do it using the browserify way, I mean: I want to have a unique bundle, without having to include additional scripts, just as browserify does (basically, without globals).

Is there anything I can do to achieve this? Is there any transform that I couldnt found or any workaround to make Angular work as a CommonJS module without exposing globals in other sources?

Comment: angular interacts with the most present global of all: the DOM, so it's never going to be a true stand-alone module like the other CommonJS ones can be. typically, commonjs mods work in webworkers, while ineligible scripts won't.

Answer (score 0):

You can user browserify-shim  inside package.json

```
"browser": {
    "angular": "./node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "angular": {
      "exports": "angular"
    },
}
```